# Parrot OS Wi-Fi connectivity issues

Tags: linux, debian, networking, wifi, parrotsec

I’ve just installed parrot 5.3 on my laptop and am having issues connecting to Wi-Fi. The SSID for my network shows up and prompts me for the password. I enter the correct password, however it will not connect and continues with the password prompt. I’ve pinged loop back with success so I know my NIC is working, however I am at a loss as to what to do next. I’ve also attempted to connect to my mobile hotspot, however I cannot even locate the network, which is odd since I have no issues finding and connecting to it on another device.

What can I do to resolve this issue and get online.